# Fill a table with elements from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a problem with my java project. I have two text files to insert in postgresql with the jdbc driver. the two files are of this type:
1) snp (rsid, chr, boolean value)
2) locus (rsid, mrna, gene, class)

I have to get two tables of this type:
1)Snp (id serial, rsid varchar, chr varchar, has_sig boolean)
2)Locus (id serial, mana_acc varchar, gene varchar, class varchar, snp_id     integer)
where snp_id of locus is foreign key references to Snp(id).

The field I can use for joining between tables is rsid which is common to both files.

I've created the table in this way:

```
st = connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snp ("
                + "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "rsid varchar(100), "
                + "chr varchar(100), "
                + "has_sig varchar(100))");
        st.executeUpdate();
        st.close();

        st = connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locus ("
                + "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "rsid varchar(100), "
                + "mrna_acc varchar(100), "
                + "gene varchar(100), "
                + "class varchar(100), "
                + "snp_id integer REFERENCES snp(id) on delete cascade on update cascade)");
        st.executeUpdate();
        st.close();
```

Then I put the files in the tables using the select query instead of the snp_id field:

```
FileSnp fs = new FileSnp("/Users/valentinafratini/Documents/Progetto Tesi/FactoryMethodDb/snp.csv");
        fs.readFile();
        while (fs.line!=null) {
            fs.line = fs.reader.readLine();

            if (fs.line!=null && fs.line.length()>0) {
                    fs.obj = fs.line.split("\\s+");
                    fs.readSingleObj();

                    st = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO snp ("
                        + "id, "
                        + "rsid, "
                        + "chr, "
                        + "has_sig) "
                        + "VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?)");
                    st.setString(1, fs.rsid);
                    st.setString(2, fs.chr);
                    st.setString(3, fs.has_sig);
                    st.executeUpdate(); 
                    st.close();

FileLocus fl = new FileLocus("/Users/valentinafratini/Documents/Progetto Tesi/FactoryMethodDb/locus.csv");
        fl.readFile();
        while (fl.line!=null) {
            fl.line = fl.reader.readLine();

            if (fl.line!=null && fl.line.length()>0) {
                    fl.obj = fl.line.split("\\s+");
                    fl.readSingleObj();

                    st = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO locus ("
                        + "id, "
                        + "rsid, "  
                        + "mrna_acc, "
                        + "gene, "
                        + "class,"
                        + "snp_id) "
                        + "VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT id FROM snp s WHERE rsid = s.rsid))");
                    st.setString(1, fl.rsid);
                    st.setString(2, fl.mrna_acc);
                    st.setString(3, fl.gene);
                    st.setString(4, fl.classe);
                    st.executeUpdate();
                    st.close();
```

But when I fill in I have the following error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Can you help me? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: The error message is quite clear - the sub-query returns more than 1 row. Either make it return max one row, or do INSERT ... SELECT ...

Comment: Do I have insert.. select.. in two different queries?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `rsid` is not unique in the table `snp`. That causes the subquery

```
SELECT id FROM snp s WHERE rsid = s.rsid
```

to return more than one row, which is the cause for the error.

I recommend that you use `INSERT ... RETURNING` to get the `id` of the row entered into `snp`:

```
INSERT INTO snp (id, ...)
VALUES (DEFAULT, ...)
RETURNING id;
```

Then bind the returned value to the placeholder in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO locus (..., snp_id)
VALUES (..., ?);
```